# Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(1)=2f(0)$. Prove that $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|<\epsilon$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to prove this:

> Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(1)=2f(0)$. Prove that $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|<\epsilon$

I considered a function $g(z)=f(z+1)-2f(z)$, which is also entire and has a zero at $z=0$, but I am not sure this is going to help me solve the problem.

Comment: The condition $f(1) = 2 f(0)$ is just there to say $f$ is either non-constant or identically $0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** Assume by contradiction that this is not true. Show that $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is entire and bounded.

Comment: I see. So, by Liouville's theorem we obtain that $g(z)$ is constant, which implies that $f(z)$ is constant. But that would mean that $f(0)=f(1)$ and therefore $f(0)=f(1)=0$, arriving at a contradiction.

Comment: @NFC Exactly... Note that the given relation is only used to deduce that $C=0$.

Answer (score 2):

I was just giving my answer a final polish edit when N.S. posted; our proofs are essentially the same, though I have fleshed out a few details.
Perhaps someone will find it useful.

If

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists z \in \Bbb C, \; \vert f(z) \vert < \epsilon \tag 1$

is ***not true***, then

$\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall z \in \Bbb C, \; \vert f(z) \vert \ge \epsilon \tag 2$

***is true***.

Thus

$g(z) = \dfrac{1}{f(z)} \tag 3$

is a well-defined entire function, and

$\forall z \in \Bbb C, \; \vert g(z) \vert = \dfrac{1}{\vert f(z) \vert} \le \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}; \tag 4$

thus $g(z)$ is a bounded entire function, hence constant by Liouville's theorem; hence $f(z)$ must be constant as well; in fact *via* (1),

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \forall z \in \Bbb C, \; \vert f(z) \vert < \epsilon \Longrightarrow \forall z \in \Bbb C, \; f(z) = 0; \tag 5$

that is, $f(z)$ is identically zero.

The hypothesis $f(1) = 2f(0)$ is not necessary to attain this result.

Comment: in (4) the RHS should be $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Also, Step (5) is wrong. You start by assuming that (1) is not true, and in Step (5) you USE (1).

Comment: And the given hypothesis is necessary, otherwise $f(z)=2019$ for example is a counterexample.... The given hypotthesis is how you fix step (5) ;)

Answer (score 1):

If $f(0)=0$ the result is immediate. If $f(0)\ne 0$, we have that $f(1)\ne f(0)$ and so $f$ is not constant. According to Picard's little theorem, a non-constant entire function takes every complex value, with one possible exception. Even if that possible exception turns out to be zero, all other complex values are attained by $f$ and the result follows.